Discrete Math on Recurrence for a $n \times n$ chessboard.
Consider a $n \times n$ chessboard. Suppose we can color each square of the chessboard either black or white at random. Let $a_n$
be the number of ways to color the chessboard so that there are no three consecutive black squares in any row or column. Find a recurrence relation for $a_n$.
In a $1 \times n$ chessboard, I found a recurrence relation:
$$
a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}
$$
However, I cannot extend this result to two dimensional case. ($n \times n$ chessboard)
I'd appreciate your help!

What's the source of this question, please?

@Gerry Myerson Unfortunately, there is not a source of two dimensional case. I thought I could extend the 1D problem to 2D, so I posted this question.

Can you clarify what your definition of adjacent here is?

@HackR I think the expression was ambiguous. I'm sorry. There are no three consecutive black squares in any row or column.

A050974, without formula though

See https://oeis.org/A202471 for the cases where the number of columns or rows is fixed. In these cases the transfer matrix method provides recurrences...

@R.J.Mathar Thank you!! But... I don't understand the recurrence relation in https://oeis.org/A202464. Could you explain?

Unless there's some Onsager-like exact solution (and even if there were, it would be an unreadable nightmare), I think you're not likely to find a closed form for the $N \times N$ case.  As pointed out in the comments, for any fixed width $k$, there is a finite-range recurrence for the $k\times N$ case, which can be found using a transfer matrix approach.
To be concrete, consider $k=3$ (for which the result is given in OEIS A292464).  The idea behind the transfer matrix is to enumerate the allowed states for any particular horizontal row (of length $3$), then describe which states can be connected to which other states when adding a new row below the current one.  Rows can clearly take on these seven values: $000$, $001$, $010$, $100$, $011$, $101$, and $110$.  These are determined by the horizontal constraint (no three 1s horizontally adjacent).  However, for the state to have enough information to enforce the vertical constraint (no three 1s vertically adjacent), we also need to track whether a given $1$ has a $1$ above it or not.  We can encode this information in the following additional states: $002$, $020$, $200$, $012$, $021$, $022$, $102$, $201$, $202$, $120$, $210$, and $220$, for a grand total of $19$ states.  The naive transfer matrix, then, will be a $19\times 19$ binary matrix $M$, where $M_{ji}=1$ whenever $i \rightarrow j$ is an allowed transition, meaning that state $j$ can occur directly beneath state $i$.  For instance, $001 \rightarrow 000,100,010,002,110,102,012$; and $220\rightarrow 000,001$.
For the width-3 case only, the states have full permutation symmetry (e.g., $002 \sim 020 \sim 200$): the three columns are equivalent to one another.  So we can actually restrict ourselves to a smaller set of six states ($000$, $001$, $002$, $011$, $012$, and $022$), and the transfer matrix $M$ will now contain some numbers besides zeroes and ones.  In particular, $M_{ji}$ has to count the number of ways to get from a particular state equivalent to $i$ to any state equivalent to $j$.  For instance, $001\rightarrow 000^{1}, 001^{2}, 002^{1}, 011^{1}, 012^{2}$; and $000\rightarrow 000^{1},001^{3},011^{3}$.  (Finding the $6\times 6$ symmetry-reduced version of $M$ here is a nice exercise.) Once we have the transfer matrix $M$ in hand, we can very efficiently find the counts we want.  We just need the number of ways to get from the starting state ($000$) to any other state in exactly $N$ steps.  But this is $$a(N)=\sum_{j}\langle j \vert M^N \vert 000\rangle,$$ where $M^N$ is matrix exponentiation, and so it can be computed quickly.
Now, we only needed $6$ states for $k=3$, and so there will be a range-$6$ linear recurrence giving the result (as the OEIS entry shows)... that is, $a(n)=\sum_{g=1}^{6}c_g a(n-g)$ for some fixed coefficients $c_g$. For larger $k$, we need more states; the number of states is clearly going to grow exponentially with $k$.  Similarly, the length of the necessary linear recurrence (and there always is one) should grow exponentially with $k$ as well.  So the transfer matrix method will only be useful up to somewhere in the $k=10$ to $k=20$ range, depending on how cleverly we implement it.

+1 Finding the symmetries seems to be an interesting problem on its own, if I am not mistaken it is equivalent to finding the automorphism group of the corresponding transition graph (or at least it seems related).

Yes, I think that's right.  In this case I believe it's always the maximal subgroup of permutations that preserve the three-adjacent sets... i.e., for $k=3$ it's the full $S_3$; for $k=4$ it's $S_2 \times S_2$; and for $k\ge 5$ it's just left-right reflection.  If the question were about counting, say, colorings with no more than $K$ black squares in any row or column, it'd always be a full $S_k$ symmetry, since that would preserve the membership in the row.  And in that case, the number of states would no longer grow exponentially with $k$.
